# Get-data from Web: with credentials

Tags: import, export-to-excel

[image]

Hi, I am trying to download a table with information from a website portal which downloads the table easily into excel without the credentials.
When I try to do the same with credentials I am getting this error, no matter if I do it anonymously, Windows, Basic and Web API with credentials/without.

Can you please help? I don't think it makes a difference but this is the dialogue box to enter credentials once the link is open:

[image]